# Excel find text, sum cell next to text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am writing here as a last resort, found similar tutorials and forum questions, but none of them isdoing the exact same thing (and I can’t/don’t know if/how its possible to combine different ideas in one formula/code).

Assume I have a table where I list all my furniture in the house, sorted by the rooms they are in. I need a command that will scan for an exact text in selected cell range (e.g. chair) and then sum the cell next to that (number that represents number of chairs in the room), so that I get as an output the total chairs in the house (5 in this case).

I will have over 50 items and 50 rooms and doing it manually seems obsolete.

[image]

Comment: Small tables below each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if everything is in the same columns as shown, then use the sumif() formula in the appropriate cell (I8 in this case).  No need for vba.

```
=SUMIF(C[-6],"chair",C[-5])
```

Comment: you could even combine with "=unique" to get the list of items. (only if you have excel 10+)

Answer (score 3):

If the rooms are not all in the same column, you could use SUMPRODUCT:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:E="chair"),B:F)`
In my example it checks the first 5 columns to equal the value `chair` and sums the value of the column next to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the tables containing the figures are below each other, then you can select columns B:C then insert a pivot table. You can then drag and drop column D in row headers, then column C in the aggregate column.